# Firefox spell-check not working (English GB, Windows 10 x64, ESR)

Tags: firefox, spell-check

For what must be years, now, spell-check has not been working for me in Firefox. I have tried to fix it many, many times and never succeeded.

I'm using Firefox 102.6.0 ESR on Windows 10 (x64) and have the English (GB) localisation.

Under Settings → General → Language:

- it shows the language as "English (GB)"
- "English (GB)" is also the only entry listed under "Set Alternatives"
- "Check your spelling as you type" is checked and enabled.
- Under "Choose your preferred language for displaying pages", there are "English (United Kingdom) [en-gb]" and "English [en]" listed, in that order.

I have tried reinstalling Firefox.

I have tried making a new profile, resetting my profile, clearing data, everything.

I have done a lot of searching on the web and found nothing helpful.

Please help. Spell-check is really an essential feature. 
(Sorry for any typos in this question because ... obvs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between language and dictionary. You may have a language pack installed but no dictionary.

From [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1380525#:%7E:text=The%20spelling%20checker%20is%20enabled,your%20spelling%20as%20you%20type%22) - try this: Go to Firefox Language Tools and force the GB EN dictionary to be installed:

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/language-tools/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have dictionaries installed and enabled:

`about:addons` and then `dictionaries`. You might have to download a new one from the add-on manager

The "Choose your preferred language for displaying pages" is just for the menu texts, and the "language" is just a tag sent to webpages that support multi-language display.